# Bootstrap select list is empty - Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to fill my Bootstrap list with items from a database, and here is what I've done yet:

Here is my HTML:

There is also [(ngModel)]="mainGroups"

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Group category:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
       <select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
          data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="articleGroups" [(ngModel)]="mainGroups">

        </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is my `ts` file content:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-new',
  templateUrl: './product-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-new.component.css']
})
export class ArticleNewComponent implements OnInit {

  id: string;
  article: Article;
  // Here I'm creating array that will hold all my categories / groups
  mainGroups: Observable<Group[]>;

  constructor(private _groupService: GroupService) {

    this.article = new Article();
    this.article.isActive = true;
    // Here I'm getting all groups and definately they are not empty
    this.mainGroups = this._groupService.getAll();
  }
}
```

Here is my `categories.service.ts` file, which is providing me getAll method:

```
  getAll(): Observable<Group[]> {
    return this._http.get<Group[]>(url)
      .catch(
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return Observable.throw(error);
        });
  }
```

And after all my select list is empty and it looks like this:

[image]

Any kind of help and suggestions would be awesome!

And please note because this is my first angular app, is it ok to instantiate model object in a contructor before I bind it with ngModel or it should be done somewhere else?
Or maybe I should not use directly model properties in ngModel, that means I should create a local variables which should be binded and on save I would create new object and fill it's properties with those variables values?

Thanks

> EDIT after David's help, possible solution 2:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Grupa:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
                            data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="articleGroups" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup">
                      <option [ngValue]="group" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups">{{group.title}}</option>
                    </select>
     </div>
  </div>


  mainGroups: Group[];

  constructor(private _globalHelperService: GlobalHelperService, private _groupService: GroupService) {

    this._groupService.getAll().subscribe(groups => this.mainGroups = groups);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a `ngModel` bound to ab observable.

You need to subcribe

```
mainGroups: Group[];
this._groupService.getAll().subscribe( groups =>  this.mainGroups = groups);
```

Or use `async` pipe

**Edit**

```
mainGroups: Observable<Group[]>;
selectedGroup: Group;


<select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
      data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="articleGroups" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedGroup">
     <option [ngValue]="group" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups | async">{{group.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

**Edit 2**

The `async` pipe  can be used so that you don't have to manually manage subcriptions. Most properties expect an actual value to work with, not an observable

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

The 2 way binding needs to be on the selected value, not on the list itself

Comment: still it's empty, maybe I should do smth inside a <select> tag ? manually add options for each item ?

Comment: Yes, that too actually

Comment: can you explain your code please, it works as expected but I dont understand it, why you are not two way bindings mainGroups lists, I'm confused little bit :(

Comment: and I realized that you've implemented async and I don't know why is that?

Comment: check for my Edit question please, I added possible solution so I'm wondering is it allright?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `<option>` tag inside the `<select>` tag. If you need to populate a dropdown menu do something like this.

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedGroup" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="sel2">
    <option [value]="i" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups">{{group}}</option>
</select>
```